# Distinctcount entrys with date slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

this is probably pretty simple but I couldn't find any solution.

I have 2 tables: ***'DateTime'*** and ***'Usage'*** and I am using a date slicer (from to) which refers to ***'DateTime'[Date]***. Now I want to DISTINCTCOUNT ***'Usage'[LPNumber]*** but only the ones which have a date that is included by the slicer. The table ***'Usage'*** does also have a column with dates: ***'Usage'[ConnectionStart Day]***

I tried this but getting an error:

```
ActiveLP = 
VAR start_date =
    MIN ( 'DateTime'[Date] )
VAR end_date =
    MAX ( 'DateTime'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT( 'Usage'[LPNumber] );
        FILTER(
            'Usage';
            'Usage'[ConnectionStart Day] >= start_date
            && 'Usage'[ConnectionStart Day] <= end_date
        )
    )
```

The error says: A circular dependency was detected: DateTime[different columns]

Can someone please help me? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a realtionship between your `DateTime` table and your `Usage` table (by the date). Then use this simple measure:

```
Distinct Count = Distinctcount('Usage'[LPNumber])
```

If you put now a slicer (from the `DateTime` table) on your report and filter it, the other table also get filtered, because of the relationship. Thus the value of `Distinct Count` will change, according to your date slicer.

Comment: Thank you very much! As you can clearly see… I am still learning